# Peclet Number and first principle for open system

Tags: thermodynamics

The Peclet number express the ratio between the heat transferred by advection and by conduction (diffusion). If it is sufficiently high the heat transferred by conduction can be neglected with respect to the other term. In a book I've found that the first principle of thermodynamic applied to a tube, under the assumption of high Pe, is the well known formula:

$$Q=mC_p(T_{in}-T_{out})$$

How should this be modified if the previous assumption is not fulfilled?

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\sum m(h+z+v^2/2)+Q-L$$

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to model a lumped system, is that right? You would normal use Peclet for mass transfer and Biot for the heat transfer. If Bi is very small then the second equation can simply be used the way it is right now. If not, then such assumption would not work and you would need to whether use spatial variation of energy or split the system in small subsystems.

Answer (score 1):

If the convection cannot be neglected, then you need to add Newton's law term to the heat balance. The second term is the law of conservation of energy and Q includes all the heat applied to the body, so no modification should be made.